# how to show more than tagify(js) in the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagify

here is my code , i want to add more than input in the same page because i am using php loop

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[name="input-custom-dropdown"]'),
 
    tagify = new Tagify(input, {
      whitelist: ["A# .NET", "A# (Axiom)", "A-0 System", "A+", "A++", "ABAP", "ABC", "ABC ALGOL", "ABSET", "ABSYS", "ACC", "Accent", "Ace DASL", "ACL2", "Avicsoft", "ACT-III", "Action!", "ActionScript", "Ada", "Adenine", "Agda", "Agilent VEE", "Agora", "AIMMS", "Alef", "ALF", "ALGOL 58", "ALGOL 60", "ALGOL 68", "ALGOL W", "Alice", "Alma-0", "AmbientTalk", "Amiga E", "AMOS", "AMPL", "Apex (Salesforce.com)", "APL", "AppleScript", "Arc", "ARexx", "Argus", "AspectJ", "Assembly language", "ATS", "Ateji PX", "AutoHotkey", "Autocoder", "AutoIt", "AutoLISP / Visual LISP", "Averest", "AWK", "Axum", "Active Server Pages", "ASP.NET", "B", "Babbage", "Bash", "BASIC", "bc", "BCPL", "BeanShell", "Batch (Windows/Dos)", "Bertrand", "BETA", "Bigwig", "Bistro", "BitC", "BLISS", "Blockly", "BlooP", "Blue", "Boo", "Boomerang", "Bourne shell (including bash and ksh)", "BREW", "BPEL", "B", "C--", "C++ – ISO/IEC 14882", "C# – ISO/IEC 23270", "C/AL", "Caché ObjectScript", "C Shell", "Caml", "Cayenne", "CDuce", "Cecil", "Cesil", "Céu", "Ceylon", "CFEngine", "CFML", "Cg", "Ch", "Chapel", "Charity", "Charm", "Chef", "CHILL", "CHIP-8", "chomski", "ChucK", "CICS", "Cilk", "Citrine (programming language)", "CL (IBM)", "Claire", "Clarion", "Clean", "Clipper", "CLIPS", "CLIST", "Clojure", "CLU", "CMS-2", "COBOL – ISO/IEC 1989", "CobolScript – COBOL Scripting language", "Cobra", "CODE", "CoffeeScript", "ColdFusion", "COMAL", "Combined Programming Language (CPL)", "COMIT", "Common Intermediate Language (CIL)", "Common Lisp (also known as CL)", "COMPASS", "Component Pascal", "Constraint Handling Rules (CHR)", "COMTRAN", "Converge", "Cool", "Coq", "Coral 66", "Corn", "CorVision", "COWSEL", "CPL", "CPL", "Cryptol", "csh", "Csound", "CSP", "CUDA", "Curl", "Curry", "Cybil", "Cyclone", "Cython", "Java", "Javascript", "M2001", "M4", "M#", "Machine code", "MAD (Michigan Algorithm Decoder)", "MAD/I", "Magik", "Magma", "make", "Maple", "MAPPER now part of BIS", "MARK-IV now VISION:BUILDER", "Mary", "MASM Microsoft Assembly x86", "MATH-MATIC", "Mathematica", "MATLAB", "Maxima (see also Macsyma)", "Max (Max Msp – Graphical Programming Environment)", "Maya (MEL)", "MDL", "Mercury", "Mesa", "Metafont", "Microcode", "MicroScript", "MIIS", "Milk (programming language)", "MIMIC", "Mirah", "Miranda", "MIVA Script", "ML", "Model 204", "Modelica", "Modula", "Modula-2", "Modula-3", "Mohol", "MOO", "Mortran", "Mouse", "MPD", "Mathcad", "MSIL – deprecated name for CIL", "MSL", "MUMPS", "Mystic Programming L"],
      maxTags: 10,
      dropdown: {
        maxItems: 20,         
        classname: "tags-look", 
        enabled: 0,             
        closeOnSelect: false    
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the Tagify initialization on multiple `input` elements:

```js
new Tagify(input1, ...)
new Tagify(input2, ...)
new Tagify(input3, ...)
```

So if you have multiple `<input>` elements in the page, simply find them with js and pass their reference when you initialize the `Tagify` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**you can make a forEach loop for all inputs**

```
  const allInputs = querySelectorAll('input[name="input-custom-dropdown"]');

  allInputs.forEach((item) => {
        // initialize Tagify on the above input node reference
        new Tagify(item);
    });
```